# SilverStripe routing producing weird results with 3 or more parameters

Tags: controller, url-routing, silverstripe

While I have successfully set up an AjaxController for typical patterns containing $Action/$ID/$OtherID, I don't seem to know how to set up a pattern for $Action + more than two parameters.

I'm trying to handle simple "calculator" URLs as in: `myajax/add/5/6/7`

**routes.yml**

```
Director:
 rules:
   'myajax//$action/$a/$b/$c': 'AjaxPage_Controller'
```

**AjaxPage.php**

```
<?php
 class AjaxPage extends Page {
 }

 class AjaxPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
     public static $url_handlers = array(
         'myajax/add/$a/$b/$c' => 'add',
     );
     private static $allowed_actions = array (
         'add',
     );

     public function add($request){
         $v1 = (int) $request->param('a');
         $v2 = (int) $request->param('b');
         $v3 = (int) $request->param('c');
         echo json_encode(array('result' => $v1 + $v2 + $v3));
         return;
     }

 }
```

Then, when I visit: `myajax/add/5/6/7?debug_request=1` I see `404 Page not found` with the following debug info:

```
Debug (line 250 of RequestHandler.php): Testing 'myajax/add/$a!/$b!/$c' with 'add/5/6/7' on AjaxPage_Controller
Debug (line 250 of RequestHandler.php): Testing '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' with 'add/5/6/7' on AjaxPage_Controller
Debug (line 258 of RequestHandler.php): Rule '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' matched to action 'handleAction' on AjaxPage_Controller. Latest request params: array ( 'Action' => 'add', 'ID' => '5', 'OtherID' => '6', )
{"result":18}
Debug (line 250 of RequestHandler.php): Testing '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' with '' on ErrorPage_Controller
Debug (line 258 of RequestHandler.php): Rule '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' matched to action 'handleAction' on ErrorPage_Controller. Latest request params: array ( 'Action' => NULL, 'ID' => NULL, 'OtherID' => NULL, )
Debug (line 184 of RequestHandler.php): Action not set; using default action method name 'index'
```

As you see - in the middle of the debug info there is a correct result being echoed, despite of which framework still seeks fallback and produces 404.

Does anyone know what is happening here (ie. what kind of a mistake I make here)? I think I have exploited all combinations of the shift point `//` in the patterns. Each attempt was followed by dev/build and flush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's falling back to a 404 page is because the `$Action//$ID/$OtherID` only matches the `add/5/6`, so the `7` still needs to be matched.

As for why your `url_handler` isn't being matched, that comes down to what the shift point does. I'm going to use your code to try to explain it for you. Basically, the left of the shift point gets consumed by the match and the right is available for the next controller to try using.

The URL `myajax/add/5/6/7` first gets sent to the `Director`. Here it matches the `myajax//$action/$a/$b/$c`, with `$action = "add"`, `$a = "5"`, `$b = "6"` and `$c = "7"`, with nothing left to be matched.

As the shift point is directly after `myajax`, when passing control off to the `AjaxPage_Controller`, only parts to the right of `myajax` are sent along for further matching. So `AjaxPage_Controller` gets given `add/5/6/7` to match.

This doesn't match `myajax/add/$a/$b/$c` as it doesn't start with a literal `myajax` string, so the `$Action//$ID/$OtherID` handler on the `RequestHandler` class is tried. This matches and sets `$Action = "add"`, `$ID = "5"` and `$OtherID = "6"`, with the 7 left over.

The `add` action is then run (you can see `{"result":18}` in your debug output) and returns nothing. Since it returns nothing, there's nothing to try matching the `7` against, so a 404 is generated as the URL hasn't been entirely processed by the last controller.

As to how to fix your code, I would change the `myajax/add/$a/$b/$c` url handler to `add//$a/$b/$c`, as the `myajax` has already been consumed and it allows for `$a`, `$b` and `$c` to all be optional.

Comment: Wonderful! That was it. Big thanks, esp. for the explanation.